# Pandas DataFrame drop duplicates keeping first 'x' occurences

Tags: python, pandas

What I am looking for is a function that works exactly like pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates() but that allows me to keep not only the first occurence but the first 'x' occurences (say like 10). Does anything like that exist?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, One way to do this would be with a `groupby` and [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html), to select the first x occurrences. As noted in the docs, `head`:

> Returns first n rows of each group.

Sample code:

```
x = 10
df.groupby('col').head(x)
```

Where `col` is the column you want to check for duplicates, and `x` is the number of occurrences you want to keep for each value in `col`

For instance:

```
In [81]: df.head()
Out[81]:
   a         b
0  3  0.912355
1  3  2.091888
2  3 -0.422637
3  1 -0.293578
4  2 -0.817454
....

# keep 3 first instances of each value in column a:

x = 3
df.groupby('a').head(x)

Out[82]:
   a         b
0  3  0.912355
1  3  2.091888
2  3 -0.422637
3  1 -0.293578
4  2 -0.817454
5  1  1.476599
6  1  0.898684
8  2 -0.824963
9  2 -0.290499
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. It perfectly solves the problem. Thanks!